# How to turn a 'wemos mini' module into a web service? Is it even possible?

Tags: arduino, webserver, wifi

So I'm trying to make a wemos mini module (d1 series) into a web server to have it run different commands.
(Let's say turn on/off or even blink every few seconds.)

I have written some code (in arduino) but I doesn't quite work. I wonder what the problem might be.

This is what I got so far:

```
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESPAsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const char* ssid = "ssid name";
const char* password = "ssid password";


#define ledPin LED_BUILTIN
WiFiServer server(80);


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(10);
    
    
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    
    // Connect to WiFi network
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
 
    // Start the server
    server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
        request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html, processor);
    });
    server.on("/on", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
        request->send_P(200, "text/plain", on().c_str());
    });
    server.on("/off", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
        request->send_P(200, "text/plain", off().c_str());
    });
    server.on("/blink", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
        request->send_P(200, "text/plain", blink().c_str());
    });
    server.onNotFound(notFound);
    server.begin();
    Serial.println("Server started");
    
    // Print the IP address
    Serial.print("Use this URL : ");
    Serial.print("http://");
    Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.println("/");
    
}
 
void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected
    on_led();
    off_led();
    blink_led();
 
}
```

I really appreciate your time. Thank you.

Comment: you mixed WiFiServer and WebServer examples. your server should be WebServer, not WiFiServer. loop should have server.handleClient(); ...

Answer (score -1):

it seems you forgot to declare some function you use in loop function.

```
on_led();
off_led();
blink_led();
```

and also the function you use in server address:

```
processor();
on();
off();
blink();
```

I think you need some thing like this:

```
int on_flag = 0;
int off_flag = 0;
int blink_flag = 1;
String on()
{
    on_flag = 1;
    off_flag = 0;
    blink_flag = 0;
    return String("Ok");
}
String off()
{
    on_flag = 0;
    off_flag = 1;
    blink_flag = 0;
    return String("Ok");
}
String blink()
{
    on_flag = 0;
    off_flag = 0;
    blink_flag = 1;
    return String("Ok");
}

void on_led(){
    if (on_flag){
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
}

void off_led(){
    if (off_flag){
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }
}
int del = 500 // 0.5 Sec
void blink_led(){
    if (blink_flag){
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
        delay(del);
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        delay(del);
    }
}
```

with these codes you'll be able to turn on or off the led or make it blink every 0.5 sec with request from local server.
be aware, in steps further, you need to make a char array and make a html page with processor function and use JS to deal with request.

I hope it would work for you.